# Aginity Stored Procedure Error

Tags: stored-procedures, netezza

This may be a layman question. Still I surfed on the web and couldn't get through.
I am getting following error when run simple stored Procedure in Aginity

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test() 
RETURNS VARCHAR(10) 
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
DECLARE 
BEGIN 
RETURN "SUCCESS" 
END
END_PROC;
```

No error given when running the above.

Get the error ONLY when execute as follows

```
EXECUTE TEST();
```

Error:

```
ERROR [01000] NOTICE:  plpgsql: ERROR during compile of TEST near line 3

ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  missing ; at end of SQL statement
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test() 
RETURNS VARCHAR(10) 
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
-- No need a DECLARE when you don have to declare anything
BEGIN 
RETURN "SUCCESS" ; -- you just need a semi colon!
END; -- also here
END_PROC;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But why it doesn't give any error while creating the procedure and is there a particular rule with regards to semi colon placement. I did another stored proc but gave different error. So it will be great if you could propose any good guide reference with regard to Netezza stored Proc.

Comment: @MPH I know well about Oracle stored procedures, but not the Netezza version, though I heard about it.

Comment: Here are the [stored procedure docs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.sproc.doc/c_sproc_stored_procs.html). The rule is that you need to put a semicolon wherever you finish a statement. For example, BEGIN is not a statement by itself, but together with the BEGIN...END block, so it does not need a semicolon. END does.